# Confusion With `if let` Statement Scope

Tags: if-statement, rust, borrow-checker

Why does the following code not compile?

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = "test".to_string();

    if let Some(first_five) = s.get(..5) {
        // ...
    }
    else {
        s.push('s');
    }
}
```

The error I get says immutable borrow occurs on line 4 (`s.get(..5)`) and that the immutable borrow ends on line 9.  Why does it end on line 9?  It seems that the scope for `s.get(..5)` should have ended on line 6, which would release the immutable reference, allowing the mutable reference to be taken on line 8 (`s.push('s')`).

The following code is a work around but it is not very idiomatic and not something I would like to use.

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = "test".to_string();

    let mut flag = false;
    if let Some(first_five) = s.get(..5) {
        //  ...
    }
    else {
        flag = true;
    }

    if flag {
        s.push('s');
    }
}
```

To reiterate, is there a reason that `s` is borrowed for much longer than it needs to be?  The return value of `s.get(..5)` is out of scope and inaccessible from the else clause so why is the string still being borrowed in the else clause?

Comment: If you are not going to use `first_five` (silly assumption, probably) you can avoid the borrow with `Some(_)`, `.is_some()`, or just checking the length of the string.